# Xamarin Forms: View, async functions, HttpClient and webapi calls

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, xamarin.forms

I should ask an advice. I'm creating an internal application for my company and I've implemented a synchronization procedure. This procedure read all records from the application database and send them to the main server. There are a lot of tables. I want to show a progressbar and a text to inform the user what the application is doing.

For that I have a **View** with the progressbar and textbox, a **ViewModel** to update the Progress value in the progressbar and the text. In this ViewModel I'm calling another function: this function is a **web client (HttpClient)** to send to my **webapi** all records. For each important event (Network error, update status, sync done and so on) this function raises a **event** that the ViewModel receives this event and update itself and then the view.

Generally speaking all the process is working but... the view is very fast and it doesn't show the message step by step. I mean when I call the webapi with *async*. The main procedure opens a lot of instance against the client function and in background the application calls the webapi.

Then I inserted for each call to an async function `.ConfigureAwait(false)` but I didn't notice a real difference.

Sometimes I received an error

> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/44931ae8/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143

and the application is freezing.

Then my question is: what is the best way to manage this kind of activities?

Comment: I hope this post will answer your question. [Click here to check Display status alert while downloading or show sattus messages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43578164/displayalert-with-changing-text-xamarin-forms/43579244?noredirect=1#comment74278572_43579244)