# DisplayAlert With changing Text xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have a requirement where i have to show the status of the download on a DisplayAlert. But with changing text on it asynchronously.

How to achieve this?

```
  DisplayAlert("Download Info", "Downloading.....", "Ok");
```

I want to show status like...

- Connected to server
- Downloading
- Download Complete

Comment: you would probably need to write your own custom DisplayAlert to do that

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is a simple "Dynamic Alert" for Forms and `iOS` using `UIAlertController` and `Android` using a `DialogFragment` and a `Xamarin.Forms` dependency service:

#### Dependency Interface:

```
public interface IDynamicAlert
{
    void Show(string title, string message);
    void Update(string message);
    void Dismiss();
}
```

#### iOS `IDynamicAlert` Dependency Implementation:

```
public class DynamicAlert : IDynamicAlert
{
    UIAlertController alert;

    public void Show(string title, string message)
    {
        if (alert != null) throw new Exception("DynamicAlert already showing");
        alert = UIAlertController.Create(title, message, UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
        var rootVC = UIApplication.SharedApplication.Windows[0].RootViewController;
        rootVC.PresentViewController(alert, true, () =>
        {
        });
    }

    public void Update(string message)
    {
        if (alert == null) throw new Exception("DynamicAlert is not showing, call Show first");
        alert.Message = message;
    }

    public void Dismiss()
    {
        if (alert == null) throw new Exception("DynamicAlert is not showing, call Show first");
        alert.DismissViewController(true, () =>
        {
            alert.Dispose();
            alert = null;
        });
    }
}
```

#### Example Usage:

```
var alert = DependencyService.Get<IDynamicAlert>();
if (alert != null)
{
    alert.Show("StackOverflow", "Starting your request...");
    await Task.Delay(2000); // Do some work...
    alert.Update("Your request is processing...");
    await Task.Delay(2000); // Do some work...
    alert.Update("Your request is complete...");
    await Task.Delay(750);
    alert.Dismiss();
}
else
{
    throw new Exception("IDynamicAlert Dependency not found");
}
```

#### Output:

[image]

#### Android Version:

The android version consists of a couple of parts, a `DialogFragment` subclass and the `IDynamicAlert` implementation that uses the custom `DialogFragment`.

#### Android DialogFragment Subclass:

```
public class DynamicAlertDialogFragment : DialogFragment
{
    AlertDialog alertDialog;
    readonly Context context;

    public static DynamicAlertDialogFragment Instance(Context context, string title, string message)
    {
        var fragment = new DynamicAlertDialogFragment(context);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.PutString("title", title);
        bundle.PutString("message", message);
        fragment.Arguments = bundle;
        return fragment;
    }

    public DynamicAlertDialogFragment(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public override Dialog OnCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        var title = Arguments.GetString("title");
        var message = Arguments.GetString("message");
        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                    .SetIcon(Android.Resource.Drawable.IcDialogInfo)
                    .SetTitle(title)
                    .SetMessage(message)
                    .Create();
        return alertDialog;
    }

    public void SetMessage(string message)
    {
        (context as Activity).RunOnUiThread(() => { alertDialog.SetMessage(message);});
    }
}
```

#### Android `IDynamicAlert` Dependency Implementation:

```
public class DynamicAlert : IDynamicAlert
{
    const string FRAGMENT_TAG = "DynamicAlert_Fragment";
    DynamicAlertDialogFragment fragment;
    static FormsAppCompatActivity currentActivity;
    public static FormsAppCompatActivity CurrentActivity { set { currentActivity = value; } }

    public void Show(string title, string message)
    {
        if (currentActivity == null) throw new Exception("DynamicAlert.CurrentActivity needs assigned");
        var fragMgr = currentActivity.FragmentManager;
        var fragTransaction = fragMgr.BeginTransaction();
        var previous = fragMgr.FindFragmentByTag(FRAGMENT_TAG);
        if (previous != null)
        {
            fragTransaction.Remove(previous);
        }
        fragTransaction.DisallowAddToBackStack();
        fragment = DynamicAlertDialogFragment.Instance(currentActivity, title, message);
        fragment.Show(fragMgr, FRAGMENT_TAG);
    }

    public void Update(string message)
    {
        if (fragment == null) throw new Exception("DynamicAlert is not showing, call Show first");
        fragment.SetMessage(message);
    }

    public void Dismiss()
    {
        if (fragment == null) throw new Exception("DynamicAlert is not showing, call Show first");
        fragment.Dismiss();
        fragment.Dispose();
        fragment = null;
    }
}
```

#### Android Init / Usage:

When creating the `AlertDialog` in the `DialogFragment` we need access to the current `Activity` and when using `Xamarin.Forms`, that is normally the `MainActivity` that is a `FormsAppCompatActivity` subclass. Thus you will need to initialize the `DynamicAlert.CurrentActivity` static property with this `Activity` in your `MainActivity.OnCreate` subclass:

Example:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
    ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
    base.OnCreate(bundle);

    ////////////
    DynamicAlert.CurrentActivity = this;
    ////////////

    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
    LoadApplication(new App());
```

}

#### Android Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you thats perfect. Can you give me a hint how can we do it in Android?

Comment: @NewbieIOS You can use a `DialogFragment` and make it work with Xamarin.Forms via a dependency service. I can post an example later as I have been using these for a while with Form projects.

Comment: you saved lot of my time. Thank you so much. Appreciate it.

Comment: Don't forget to register your implementations with the Dependency Service with.   "[assembly: Dependency(typeof(DynamicAlert))]"    above the namespace of each implementation.