# Xamarin Dependency Service with context

Tags: android, xamarin

I have a problem with the dependency services for implementing features that depends of the plattorm. I need what my implementation on Android receive a Context object to do the task. How can I do it?

This is my code:

1) On PCL:

```
public interface ICallService
{        
    List<string> GetContacts(); 
}
```

2) On Android Project:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(CallService))]
namespace DEMOBLOBS.Droid.DependencyServicesPruebas
{
    public class CallService : ICallService
    {
        public static void Init() { }

        public List<string> GetContacts()
        {
           AT THIS POINT I NEED THE CONTEXT OBJECT!
        }

    }

}
```

The constructor of Call Service class does not have any parameter. Maybe I can I pass the Context object like parameter in some way?

Can you help me, please?

Comment: Review the Android section of my answer on this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43579244/4984832

Comment: Thank you, now it works fine!

Answer (score 3):

you could try answer from https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/106938/context-is-obsolete-as-of-version-2-5

```cs
internal static MainActivity Instance { get; private set; }

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle) 
{
  Instance = this;

  // Forms initialization here...
}

//later where  you need it:
var context = MainActivity.Instance;
```